# Module for Pretty Printing HTML?

Tags: node.js, npm, commonjs, gruntjs

I'm working on a grunt build file which hits a URL and writes the output to a static HTML file. The url I'm hitting has compressed HTML and I'd like to pretty print it before writing to the static file. Are there any good modules for doing this? I've looked around and it seems like Max Ogden's html prettyprinter is my closest option (https://github.com/maxogden/commonjs-html-prettyprinter). Maybe if I combine it with the grunt-shell task or something? Really I'd prefer to just require a module in grunt and say pretty(my-file.html) and then write that using fs but so far that is proving elusive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You found all the resources you need. That module does it for you.

```
var html = require("html");
var data = '<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>';
var prettyData = html.prettyPrint(data, {indent_size: 2});
process.stdout.write(prettyData)
```

Look at it's [source](https://github.com/maxogden/commonjs-html-prettyprinter/blob/master/bin/html.js).

---

Or you could use [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to execute the command found in the README: `html *.html`.

Comment: awesome, thank you! my node-fu is not super strong. I ended up sending it to fs.writeFileSync like this:

fs.writeFileSync( dest, html.prettyPrint(body, { indent_size: 2 }));

where dest is the final file path and body is the http response body. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for alternatives (perhaps because a project has been abandoned, or you don't like the API), you can use NPM's website to search for others. Here are a few options: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=html%20prettify I sorted by popularity and picked the first one, [pretty](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/pretty).

The code ends up looking pretty similar to the accepted answer:

```js
import pretty from 'pretty';
var data = '<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>';
var prettyData = pretty(data);
process.stdout.write(prettyData)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :) Tried `html-format` and `html-prettify`, but `pretty` better suited my needs. Also, love how you included a timeless solution -- to simply go through that list ⭐