# Print to specific printer from js

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension

i have build a web app for a business that print about 300 pages a day that needed to print on 3 kinds of paper(3 trays) on one printer.
because of the high number of pages we cant afford the time of selecting the printer and hit ok.
we need that in one click the system will send a print job to the right try.

what are my options ?

the server have vb.net on server 2008 and can be connected to the printer.
the clint uses chrome web browser and run on windows.

i dont mind if the solution will be on client side or server side.

Comment: I would look into nodejs.

Comment: server side or clint side? do you know about a way to print from a nodejs app an html file with the css?

Comment: Server side ... it would have to use something like Pretty Print: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875375/module-for-pretty-printing-html